# How to hide status and navigation bars after first touch event?

Tags: android, show-hide, android-statusbar

I have been using the flags `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` to hide and show both the status and navigation bars. They are working correctly. I am hiding them as the activity starts and I want to show them again on touch event. Android automatically shows them on first touch event (this first touch event is not passed to my app). I'm thinking to use `sendMessageDelayed()` to hide both the bars after a certain time. How could I use this first touch event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it by using `View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`. I have just used a `Handler.sendMessageDelayed` inside the if condition when both status and navigation bars are visible. See the below implementation for clarity.

Source : [Responding to UI Visibility Changes](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html)

```
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {@Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(HIDE_STATUSBAR); //Implement your hide functionality accordingly                
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 3000);
        } else {
            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired

            }
        }
    }
});
```

The disadvantage with this approach is the first touch event could not be used by your app. I think you have to use other approaches like [WindowManager.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) or [Immersive Fullscreen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) in that case.

Comment: this approach is working fine to hide bars but when soft keyboard is getting displayed, its coming with a jerk...any idea whats causing that?

Comment: Not sure what's causing the flicker but try playing with this attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode`

Answer (score 0):

-If you want to hide the navigation bar, you will encounter the problem with the first touch event and your app will not be able to do anything with it.

-If you want you can use `postDelayed()` to hide the bars after certain time, here is what I have done:

```
Runnable navHider = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("HIDING", "hide");
        hideSystemUi();
    }

/** Hides StatusBar and NavigationBar */
private void hideSystemUi() {
    if (isLandscape()) {
        // Set flags for hiding status bar and navigation bar
        View decorView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView();
         // Hide the status bar.
         int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    }
}

private void setVisibilityChangeListener() {
    View decorView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none
                    // of the
                    // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are
                    // set.
                    if (isLandscape()) {
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            getHandler().postDelayed(navHider,
                                    UI_VISIBILITY_TIME);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

What we are doing here is:

-First, the `navHider` is a Runnable object which is hiding the systemUI.

-Second, the `hideSystemUi` method is sets the UI options flags for hiding the status and navigation bar (Note that we are also using `LAYOUT_STABLE` Flag so the content would appear behind  the status bar and navigation bars and we wont need to resize the content.)

-Third, we are using the `systemUIVisibilityChangeListener`, so that after the user interacts with the screen and the status and navigation bars show, we use the `postDelayed()`, where the UIVisibility time is the time, you want to wait before we hide the status and navigation bars

You can also show/hide the status bar on every touch event (or clicking a button and etc) We can do this only for the status bar but not for the navigation bar:

```
/** Hides StatusBar and NavigationBar */
private void hideSystemUi() {
    if (isLandscape()) {
        // Set flags for hiding status bar and navigation bar
        View decorView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView();
        // // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        Window window = ((Activity) context).getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        ((Activity) context).getActionBar().hide();
        isShowing = false;
    }
}

private void showSystemUi() {
    View decorView = ((Activity) context).getWindow().getDecorView();
    Window window = ((Activity) context).getWindow();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
    ((Activity) context).getActionBar().show();
    isShowing = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (isShowing) {
            Log.e("onInterceptTouchEvent", "Hiding System UI");
            hideSystemUi();
        } else {
            Log.e("onInterceptTouchEvent", "Showing System UI");
            showSystemUi();
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Note that in those 2 methods: `hideSystemUI()` and `showSystemUI()`, to avoid the annoying "first touch event" we are using the old pre 4.0 flags, for hiding the status bar.

I am using this code in my `ViewPager` (Which I am using to show images), so I can override the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method. Here I check if the system is showing or not, with a simple boolean. Also you need to use `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, this will allow you to scroll the `ViewPager`, without actually showing/hiding the status bar accidentally, so you can scroll in fullscreen mode.

What you can do is make a custom layout (Lets say `RelativeLayout`), which extends `ViewGroup` and you can overwrite `onInterceptTouchEvent` and make this implementation. The touch event will work only on that `CustomRelativeLayout`, so if you want for it to work on the whole activity, just make `CustomRelativeLayout` your base layout with the `match_parent` attributes for height/width.

Here is info for showing and hiding status and navigation bars.
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

And this is a link, for managing touch events.
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html